# 500 server error while using Symfony class

Tags: php, symfony, ubuntu

Im trying to run Symfony Crawler in my script, but when I try to do that, I get 500 server error. Where is the problem? The code:

```
use Symfony\Component\DomCrawler\Crawler;

class Yt_downloader
{
    private $__parser;
    private $__uri;

    public function __construct($cfg)
    {
        $this->__parser = new Crawler();

        if ( is_array($cfg) ) {
            foreach ( $cfg as $key => $value ) {
                $this->{$key} = $value;
            }
        }
    }

    public function test()
    {
        print_r($this->__uri);
    }
}
```

and the action:

```
    require_once APPPATH . 'libraries/Yt_downloader.php';
    $downloader = new Yt_downloader(array(
        '__uri' => 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=...'
    ));
```

btw, my composer.json:

```
    {
  "name": "project",
  "description": "",
  "license": "MIT",
  "require-dev": {
    "symfony/css-selector": "~2.8|~3.0"
  },
  "suggest": {
    "symfony/css-selector": ""
  },
  "autoload": {
    "psr-4": { "Symfony\\Component\\DomCrawler\\": "" }
  },
  "minimum-stability": "dev",
  "extra": {
    "branch-alias": {
      "dev-master": "3.0-dev"
    }
  }
}
```

this is being used in Codeigniter project. I thought it can be composer problem, but when I try to use different library it works. I think there is a problem with namespaces or something. Maybe I can see log anywhere? I use ubuntu..

Comment: Can you post the 500 error message?

Comment: I just debugged it and I see that class `Crawler` is not found. Then I found, that it should be stored in Components directory, which is not found in my `vendor/symfony/` folder.. but the next question would be - how to download crawler components

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to require

```
"symfony/dom-crawler": "~2.8|~3.0"
```

In your composer.json file so that the crawler component is installed